# What is the progress bar at the bottom of Dbeaver for?

Tags: dbeaver

(Added Postgres tag because this may or may not be a Postgres issue, I suspect it may be to do with the tool I am using, Dbeaver but I do not know for sure)

I have bee struggling with a query that used to take ~5 minutes to run. Even after a few hours, today it does not run.

I noticed a progress bar at the bottom of Dbeaver and I cannot recall if this was there before, it might be just that I am looking more closely since I've ben struggling with my query.

I notice that the progress bar has a range of between ~50M and 112M. As the progress bar moves up closer to 112M, it goes back to 50 and starts again, never completing.

Could this be related to my query not completing? What does this progress bar signify?
[image]

Comment: That looks like an indicator how much memory DBeaver is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bar indicates the java heap size and status. The settings for hiding the heap status can be found at the general preferences:
[dbeaver heap size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZC9t.png)